The equioscillation theorem for Haar manifolds
I am searching for a non-linear generalization of Chebyshev's equioscillation theorem for Haar spaces $V\subseteq\mathcal{C}([a,b])$, where $\mathcal{C}([a,b])$ denotes continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $f\in\mathcal{C}([a,b])$ and $V\subseteq\mathcal{C}([a,b])$ be an $N$-dimensional Haar space. Then $v^*\in V$ is a best approximation to $f$ in the suprememum norm iff there are points $a\leq x_1 < \dots < x_{N+1}\leq b$ and a sign $\sigma\in\{-1,1\}$ so that $f(x_n)-v^*(x_n) = (-1)^n\sigma\|f-v^*\|$ for all $n=1,\dots,N+1$.
I am trying to do literature search to find out if someone has made a generalization of this theorem to Haar manifolds which I am not completely sure what is yet, but they should be something like subsets of $\mathcal{C}^\infty([a,b])$ that are manifolds and satisfy the Haar condition and perhaps have some restrictions on their tangent spaces.
Does anyone know about such a theorem?
